# Ionic $stateParams not defined error

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

i am a starter with ionic and angular, when following the master-detail navigation practice, i found out that the $stateParams is not working properly, when navigate to the details page, it seems the stateParams undefined, any idea? thanks

### app.js

```js
var app = angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])
  app.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})
  app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
   .state('home', {
     url: "/home",
     abstract: true,
     templateUrl: "app/home/views/home.html"
   })
    .state('home.leagues',{
     url:"/leagues",
     views:{
      "tab-leagues":{
       templateUrl:"app/home/views/leagues.html"
      }
     }
    })
    .state('home.myTeams',{
    url:"/myTeams",
    views:{
     "tab-myTeams":{
      templateUrl:"app/home/views/myTeams.html"
     }
    }
    })
   .state('sideMenu', {
    url:"/sideMenu",
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: "app/home/views/sideMenus.html",
       controller:"listCtrl"
   })
    .state('sideMenu.playlists', {
     url: "/playlists",
     views: {
      "menuContent": {
       templateUrl: "app/home/views/playlists.html"
      }
     }
   })
       .state('sideMenu.playlist',{
        url:"/playlists/:id",
        views:{
         "menuContent":{
          templateUrl:"app/home/views/playlist.html"
         }
        }
         })
       .state('sideMenu.login',{
        url:"/login",
        views:{
         "menuContent":{
          templateUrl:"app/home/views/login.html"
         }
        }
    });

  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home/leagues');
});
```

### masterPage.html

```js
<ion-view view-title="Playlists" ng-controller="listCtrl">
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item ng-repeat="playlist in playlists" href="#/sideMenu/playlists/{{playlist.id}}">
        {{playlist.title}}
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

### detailPage.html

```html
<ion-view view-title="Playlist" ng-controller="listDetailCtrl">
  <ion-content>
    <h1>{{playlist.title}}</h1>
      <span>isBinded?</span>
      <span>{{isBinded}}</span>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

### detailCtrl

```js
app.controller('listDetailCtrl',['$stateParams',function($scope,$stateParams){

 console.log("$stateParams",$stateParams);
 $scope.isBinded = "true";
}]);
```

Comment: In `detailCtrl`: change to: `app.controller('listDetailCtrl',['$scope','$stateParams',function($scope,$stateParams){`. You forgot inject `'$scope'`

Comment: In addition: In `masterPage.html` you use `ng-controller="listCtrl"` and the same controller you call from `$stateProvider`. Be aware, it might lead to double controller implementation

Comment: waha,thanks so such, it is WORKED~! and i will delete the ng-controller from app.js,cheers